# In MongoDB aggregation pipeline $lookup returning empty array

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to apply `$lookup` aggregation on two of my collections, but it is returning an  empty array each time. I have checked the data type for the local and foreign field and they are same. I am using `pymongo` library to implement it in a `Python` program.

This is the schema of `paid` collection:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"60aba58c5eff5afbc6e7c9f3"},
"created":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1621861772297"}},
"questionId: {"$oid":"60aba53d485bfcf514e0bc1d"},
"userId":"gctqXxSIrAe8O8HidhOhxzYIDjR2"
}
```

This is the schema for the `question` collection:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"60ab8e0c485bfcf514e0bc18"},
"created":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1621855756763"}},
"clientId":"ksCBoGLIr7MPNcod2FqXNPNcgZj2",
"topic":"Engineering"
}
```

Now I want to join these using `questionId` of `paid` collection and `_id` of `question` collection so I can then group by `userId` and `topic` and get the count of questions of each topic that each userId is following

I am using `$lookup` in the following way:

```
 pipeline = [{
       '$lookup':
         {
           'from': 'coll',
           'localField': 'questionId',
           'foreignField': '_id',
           'as': 'output'
         }
 }]

records = list(paid.aggregate(pipeline))
```

This is returning an empty array. I am fetching the collections from MongoDB Atlas.
 Please someone help me out here as I am fairly new to Mongo and am using these aggregation functions for the first time.

Comment: Everything works fine.. Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gbVNstPg4s0) . I hope you need to check the field names and collection names. FYI The above `questionId` doesn't match with your given question's `_id`

Comment: @varman The Mongo Playground snippet you shared works fine and it should have for me, but when I on python it is returning an empty array. I will try it out again in the morning. And yeah `questionId` and `_id` don't match, this is just an example to show the schema, but some of the other records have a match in `questionId` and `_id` which I want.

Comment: @varman The solution you provided is not working for me. I am getting the collections from MongoDB Atlas, is that maybe posing some problem?

Comment: No, its not an issue. Did u double check all eg : fields, capital, simple cases, spaces, collection names. Its working in mongoplayground means it should work

Comment: And i dont know about python, so you may refer some mongo-python articals. Sometimes the configuration or implementation might be the problem

Comment: Finally got it working, posted it in the answer

Comment: Haha, i said that u missed something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing finally got fixed. 
 I was fetching the collections from MongoDB Atlas using `collection1 = db['question]` and `collection2 = db['paid']` and then using lookup as:

```
 pipeline = [{
       '$lookup':
         {
           'from': 'collection1',
           'localField': 'questionId',
           'foreignField': '_id',
           'as': 'output'
         }
 }]

records = list(collection2.aggregate(pipeline))
```

But, instead of this we have to use the original collection name in the `from` clause instead of the name we give after fetching the data from Atlas to Python. So the code will change to:

```
pipeline = [{
           '$lookup':
             {
               'from': 'question',
               'localField': 'questionId',
               'foreignField': '_id',
               'as': 'output'
             }
     }]
    
records = list(collection2.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Hopefully this helps someone who does the same mistake while using Pymongo and MongoDB Atlas